# How to Add a Second PHP-FPM Website as Docker Container with MongoDB?

Tags: php, mongodb, docker, nginx, traefik

I have the following local configuration: Docker Compose, Nginx, PHP-FPM for a website, MongoDB, PostgreSQL, and Traefik. They are all started with Docker Compose and running in their network. I want to add a second PHP-FPM website as a Docker container with volumes. It will use the MongoDB service and run on a different port or address. What should I do to achieve this?

```
  php-fpm:
    image: fpm-dev:latest
    volumes:
      - ./php-fpm:/app

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./php-fpm:/app
      - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx
      - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.php-fpm.rule=Host(`php-fpm.docker.localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.php-fpm.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.services.php-fpm.loadbalancer.server.port=8081"
      
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.8
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 8080:8080
       # - 8081:8081 # I've tried to add new port
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./docker/traefik/config/static.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yml:ro
      - ./docker/traefik/config/dynamic.yml:/etc/traefik/dynamic.yml:ro

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - mongo:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

Comment: The easiest way is to create a second Compose file that contains its own isolated databases and other stores.  You might need to do some extra configuration of the port-80 reverse proxy; it's a little more tied to your host than your application.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  It would probably be the easiest. However, I want the second application to stay on the network and have access to Mongo since it uses the same data.

Comment: ...so it's part of the same application?  Add another container to the existing Compose file.

Comment: It's basically the same app as fpm-php, but it works with Mongo. And the first app works with Mongo and Postgres. This makes it easier to test the switch from Mongo to Postgres.